# What new settings should be created when installing Facebook C# SDK v6.0 with NuGet?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

From the [Facebook C# SDK getting started guide](http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started):

> After you install the package you must configure the application. The
>   only setting we need to change is the 'Site URL' under the 'Website'
>   settings.

I installed the SDK using NuGet (the first time I've used NuGet) but I can't see where I am supposed to configure the 'Site URL' as per instructions. When installing the package with NuGet, should it automatically create new entries in Web.Config? It certainly didn't on my project - no new entries were created in Web.Config and I'm not sure where else I'm supposed to look.

The documentation for v6.0 seems to be sorely lacking - I can't even find a sample "Hello World" type project anywhere.

Facebook SDK Version 6.0.10.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you already have a Facebook Application created on https://developers.facebook.com/?
When you created an application, you can see them with the "Apps" navigation button on the top. One of the settings that you have set for your application is the "siteurl" setting. You have to set it to something like this: "http://localhost:57843/". The number is offcourse your port number of your ASP .NET application. You can see it in you url bar when you run the application.

Well there is some documentation. See the official website of the Facebook C# SDK: http://csharpsdk.org/.
This example will give you a working web application when you finished it: http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started
This example will ask for your application id. That is the application id of facebook that you have created above.

Comment: Thanks, I have read all of those docs (otherwise I wouldn't post here). I have a Facebook App and it's all correctly configured. What confused me is that the documentation states to configure the "Site URL". In Facebook there is a "Site domain" and "Canvas URL", but no "Site URL". So I presumed the docs were referring to some config setting in the ASP.NET application which I couldn't find. P.S. The "Getting started" example is ok but I still think a complete downloadable sample solution would be very helpful (as was the case with SDK version 5)

Comment: Specifically, can you please answer the question of whether the NuGet installation should be adding new settings to my web.config file (which it isn't doing right now) ?

Comment: Well the documentation is right. There is a "Site URL". I just checked it again by my own apps. Go to the settings on developers.facebook.com, select your app an click on the "Settings" section "Edit Settings". Under the "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" section you could enter the "Site Url" setting.

Comment: The version 6 of the SDK will not add config sections. It is not needed anymore.

Comment: My apologies - you're right, the "Site URL" is indeed there. I missed it when looking at Site Domain and Canvas URL. More importantly, thank you for confirming that my NuGet installation is configured correctly.

Comment: Your welcome. Maybe when you have everything working, you could help me with my own problem ;-). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877079/accesstoken-is-null-in-facebook-c-sharp-sdk-getting-started-tutorial